# Find the solution of the Cauchy problem $u_t-uu_x=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

> For the Cauchy problem $u_t-uu_x=0, ~x\in \mathbb{R}, t>0$ with $u(x,0)=x,~x\in \mathbb{R} $, which of the following statements is true?
>
> 1. the solution $u$ exists for all $t>0$.
> 2. the solution $u$ exists for $t<\frac{1}{2}$ and breaks down at $t=\frac{1}{2}$.
> 3. the solution $u$ exists for $t<1$ and breaks down at $t=1$
> 4. the solution $u$ exists for $t<2$ and breaks down at $t=2$.

**My work**

I used the method of characteristics to find out the solution.

Given equation is $u_t-uu_x=0$, then 
$$\frac{du}{ds}=\frac{\partial u }{\partial x}\frac{dx}{ds}+\frac{\partial u }{\partial t}\frac{dt}{ds}$$. 
$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$ , letting $t(0)=0$ , we have $t=s$

$\dfrac{du}{ds}=0$ , letting $u(0)=f(x_0)$ , we have $u(x,t)=f(x_0)$

$\dfrac{dx}{ds}=-u$ , letting $x(0)=x_0$ , we have $x=-us+x_0$ ,

Therefore $u(x,t)=f(x_0)=f(x+ut)$. Now applying the initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x)=x$ we get $u(x,t)=x+ut$.

Now the problem is from the solution I am unable to conclude anything from the option given precisely. It seems the option 1 is true but I don't know for sure. How can I solve this? Please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will solve this problem using the method of characteristic.

Suppose we could rewrite the PDE as
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}u(t, X(t)) = u_t +X'(t)u_x = u_t-uu_x=0
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
u(t, X(t))=\text{ const} \ \ \text{ and } \ \ X'(t) = -u(t, X(t)) =\text{ const}=-u(0, x_0).
\end{align}
Imposing the condition $X(0) = x_0$ yields
\begin{align}
X(t) = (1-t)x_0
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
u(t, X) = u(t, ct+x_0) = u(0, x_0) = x_0. 
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
u(t, X) = \frac{X}{1-t}.
\end{align}

Hence the solution break down when $t=1$.

Comment: OK so my solution is basically correct.  Thank you

Comment: Only in spirit. However, you still need to be very careful when handling nonlinear equation.

Comment: Yes got that.  Will be careful in future.  Thank you again,  your solution is wonderful :)